# How to render multiple models/controllers in one view in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

All of the documentation that I have found for RoR shows examples of displaying simple views with one model, for example a post model.  But lets say for example, I have several pieces of data I want to display on different sections of a page, what is the best approach to this?  If I have a section of "posts", a section of "friends" and lets say a section of "restaurants".  All three of these are separate models with separate controllers.  Do I need to create a separate controller for this page that pulls all of this data together?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, yes you should create a separate controller. This honestly is less about MVC than it is about using RESTful routes.

What you are describing sounds like a dashboard, and in cases where the controller doesn't really represent a single model or resource, it makes sense to create a one-off controller.

In this case you could create a HomeController or a DashboardController and either set it as your root in routes.rb:

```
root :to => 'home#index'
```

Or:

```
match '/home', :to => 'home#index'
```